# how to define specific XML element in XPath to delete with xmlStarlet?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to use xmlStarlet to delete a particular element in an XML file and I am having problems with the XPath specification. This is the node/element that I need to delete, i.e., specify in XPath:

```
   <ShowFrame/>
      <DoAction>
         <actions>
            <Stop/>
            <EndAction/>
         </actions>
      </DoAction>
   <ShowFrame/>
```

The problem is that there are other DoAction elements with an actions child that I do not want to delete. Only the DoAction elements with a child actions which has those 2 children: Stop and EndAction. The DoAction elements that I do not want to delete have different children in the actions child.

When I use this XPath specification in the delete xmlStarlet command only the Stop descendant is deleted:

"/swf/Header/tags/DoAction/descendant::actions/descendant::Stop"

but I want to delete the complete DoAction element. Actually, I really need to also delete the ShowFrame element following the DoAction element so there is not 2 adjacent ShowFrame elements remaining after the deletion.

I have been trying to study the XPath spec but I don't understand it. The examples I find use attributes but there are no attributes in this XML file.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Andres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
/swf/Header/tags/DoAction[actions[Stop and EndAction]]
```

Above xpath select `DoAction` element with child `actions` contains both `Stop` and `EndAction` children.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it should work

```
//DoAction[*/EndAction or */Stop]
```